# Automate test run using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have used Selenium IDE to automate some basic screens of a website and they are working fine. However, just wanted to understand if there a way to automate scripts to run every 10 or 15 mins using Selenium IDE ? Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your ide tests from the command line:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp#running-selenium-server

using the htmlSuite option:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Running_IDE_scripts_with_Selenium_RC

Then you can run it from the command line with a cron job or you can use a Jenkins plug in: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Seleniumhq+Plugin